# What Am I Doing Wrong on this HTACCESS file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Someone please tell me what is wrong with this htaccess rules?

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)&type=downway1$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^search\.php$  /search\/%1\/1\/? [R=301,NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)&type=(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^search\.php$  /search\/%1\/%2\/1\/? [R=301,NC,L]

 RewriteRule search/(.*)/(.*)/$  /search.php?q=$1&page=$2 [L] <-- this and
 RewriteRule search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$  /search.php?q=$1&type=$2&page=$3 [L] <-- this
```

are not working in same time. for example TYPE = app Q = windows

if I search type by downway1 it works powerfully but if I search in app type Q becomes windows/app not only windows. help me please!

edit: im trying to redirect `"search.php?q=someterm&page=1"` to `"/search/someterm/1/"` and `"search.php?q=someterm&type=sometype&page=1"` to `"/search/sometype/someterm/1/"`

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you tell us what it's actually supposed to do in the first place. If not, raise your rewrite log level and start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are applied in order. In this case, `/search/(.*)/(.*)/$` is tested first, and actually **does** match `/search/windows/app/1/`, because the dot operator matches everything, *including forward slashes*.

Try switching the order of the rules, or, even better, make them order independent by changing `(.*)` to `([^/]*)`, which means match everything, *except forward slashes*. This will make the first test fail for `/search/windows/app/1/`, so apache will move on to the second.

Comment: I'm getting "Attempting to open is not going to end any time entered into a routing loop." error. :((